# Does trigger_error interrupt script?

Tags: php

In runtime the log file contains the message I set to the argument of `trigger_error`. The page is blank after that ! Is it possible to continue code execution after `trigger_error` ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

No, [`trigger_error()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trigger-error.php) does not stop execution unless you pass the second argument as `E_USER_ERROR`. By default it triggers a warning. You must have an error at some point after the call.

Trigger Warning:

```
trigger_error("CTest message"); // defaults to E_USER_NOTICE
```

Trigger Fatal Error:

```
trigger_error("Test message", E_USER_ERROR);
```

Comment: Yes the second argument is E_USER_ERROR : in fact I am testing a session destruction , the garbage collector removes successfully database session data , and when I try to reload the page which creates a session then the trigger_error is raised !

Comment: `E_USER_ERROR` will stop execution, remove the argument or change to E_USER_NOTICE

Comment: If you set a custom error handler you can allow E_USER_ERROR to continue execution by not returning `false`.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on what the second parameter you pass to the [`trigger_error()`](http://php.net/trigger_error) function, `$error_type`, is. Some will display the error and stop execution, others will display an error and continue (note, the display is also based on your `error_reporting` and `display_errors` settings).

For instance, if you call:

```
trigger_error('This is an error', E_USER_ERROR);
```

Your script will stop execution.

However, if you call:

```
trigger_error('This is a warning', E_USER_WARNING);
```

Your script will not stop.

By default, `trigger_error()` uses `E_USER_NOTICE` which does not stop execution.

The full list of error types can be found [here](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.constants.php).

Comment: trigger_error cannot be used with E_ERROR or E_WARNING. as the php documentation for trigger_error says it only works for E_USER family of constants.